# Running script line by line automatically yet being asked before each line from second line onwards

Tags: shell-script, security, exit, testing, control-flow

I work on a script of about 20 lines which I find myself testing time and again by copy-pasting and executing line by line.

Instead of copying-pasting each line and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute, I would like to *copy-paste* the entire script without executing it in one go (as one block or an [heredocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)), but rather in a query like fashion; for example:

- The first line get's executed regularly (unconditionally) and I am being queried if I desire to continue to execute the forthcoming line (after having enough time to consider the output);
- If I choose to continue - so be it, if not, the operation breaks;
- (the result so far will not be rolled back of course, but I would at least not continue to produce further problematic result);

This pattern should be repeated line after line, until the end of the script.

Is there a utility that can help me work in this fashion?

Comment: You can use the mentioned Bash debugger and `DEBUG` trap or you can show executed commands without stopping by running `/bin/bash -x script.sh` or using `#!/bin/bash -x` on the first line of the script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [the Bash debugger](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/) to debug your scripts.

A simpler option is to use the `DEBUG` trap:

```
#!/bin/bash

function prompt {
  if [[ -n "$BASH_COMMAND" ]]; then
    echo About to run \'$BASH_COMMAND\'
    read -p 'Continue [Y/n]?' CONT
    if [[ "$CONT" = "n" || "$CONT" = "N" ]]; then
      echo Exiting prematurely
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
}

trap prompt DEBUG

echo Hello
ls
sleep 10
```

This will run the `prompt` function before every command, once the trap is set, giving you the option to continue or abort. The lines starting with `echo Hello` would be replaced by whatever your script is, or better yet, you could store the function and `trap` command in a separate scriptlet which you’d `source` inside the script you want to debug.

There are some subtleties associated with the `DEBUG` trap; for one, it doesn’t trigger inside functions, unless it’s been re-set inside the function (so you can skip over functions you don’t want to debug, including the `prompt` function itself, but you need to remember to run `trap` inside functions you *do* want to debug).

The tracing behaviour can be enabled and disabled at will in your script, respectively by adding

```
trap prompt DEBUG
```

and

```
trap "" DEBUG
```

as appropriate.

Comment: use `shopt -s extdebug` if you want the `DEBUG` trap to be inherited by functions _and subshells_

Comment: I just tried to copy-paste everything before `echo Hello`; I am indeed being asked to continue or not; I have one issue - if I choose not to continue, the entire window get's closed and I lose the session; how would you tackle it?

Comment: @JohnDoea the intent here was to debug a script, not an interactive session. However, you can use this to debug an interactive session by starting a new shell inside your terminal window; that way stopping the debug session will stop the second shell, not your terminal’s main shell.